# After upgrading to 18.04, Firefox is showing unnecessary lines and dots between letters

Tags: firefox, fonts

After upgrading to 18.04, Firefox shows unnecessary lines and dots between letters as shown below.

[image]

how to rectify this?

Comment: First, ensure that Firefox and everything else is fully upgraded. Run `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade` in a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T); if there are errors upgrading everything, stop and let us know. Second, reboot your computer. Is the problem still there after rebooting?

Comment: @Chai T. Rex The system is updated with no errors.  The problem still there after rebooting.